# How to make some generic functions available by many service in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, dependency-injection

Using **angular 4** with **typescript**, would it be better to

1. create another service that will be injected?
2. inherit from a base class?
3. using module import?

And **what would be the benefit of each method**?

Here is an example of my actual service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {

  }
  doSomething(id) {
    //Need to call a generic function from here.
    //That function will also be called by other services
  }
}
```

**Method #1: another service injection**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HelperService } from '../helper.service';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private helper: HelperService) {}

  doSomething(id) {
    this.helper.myHelperFunction(id);
  }
}
```

helper.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class HelperService {
  constructor() {}

  myHelperFunction(id) {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

**Method #2: Inheritance**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MyHelper } from '../helper.js';

@Injectable()
export class MyService extends MyHelper {
  constructor() {}

  doSomething(id) {
    super.myHelperFunction(id);
  }
}
```

**Method #3: imports**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Helper } from '../helper.js';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  doSomething(id) {
    Helper.myHelperFunction(id);
  }
}
```

**Method #n**

Any other efficient way?

Comment: This is an opinion provoking question. These are all valid options. Are you looking for a best practice?

Comment: absolutely looking for best practices. not trying to provoke in any way

Comment: Opinions aren't bad they just aren't good for users looking for concrete answers. Another method would be to extend prototypes but I would not recommend that unless they are your own custom objects. If you want to be SOLID then the DI method is probably best practice.

Comment: would it require an instance of my base service for each service that use it?

Comment: Nope, the idea behind services is that they are singletons and only have one instance. Ideally they are stateless and can be shared between other parts of the application with no interference. (Also be sure to @user or people may not see your replies)

Comment: thanks @rjustin , that replied to my questioning regarding which way to go. I was concerned about memory usage, maintainability and generated code growth. And as they are singleton and it's part of SOLID, that fits all those concerns.